# Documentation not working when compiled to jar

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, jar, javadoc

I'm creating my own package for java with some useful classes. In a lot of them I have added some documentation. It works great when while editing the source files (I'm working with VS Code) however it does not show up when only referencing the compiled jar library. Also, when ctrl-clicking onto a class it says it failed to load the sources and just generated a template. The actual code however is running just fine.
Can someone help me? I put quite some work into the documentaion and it would be a shame to not be able to use it. By the way: I used the jar compiler from the java projects extension.

Comment: What's your documentation mean? Is it a link or a  paragraph of text? How do you add it, like put it in code or by commenting it?

Comment: I have the doc as text inside the source code

Comment: No, putting the doc text in source code then packing the .java file as jar are not able to make it success to hover and show the document. You should use [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html) to generate API documentation from Java source files.

Answer (score 0):

To make the document be shown when hovering over it, you should put the doc text after the label **Description** and use the command `javadoc` to generate API information, then pack it as JAR.

Here is a demo project:

```
/**
 * Description: This is a demo project for printing "helloworld"
 * Program Name: App
 * Date: 2020-12-16
 * @author Molly Wang
 * @version 1.0
 */
public class App {

    /**
     * member variable
     */
    public int age;

    /**
     * main method
     * @param args
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Hello, World!");
    }
}
```

Run the following command in terminal. Pay attention to enter the folder of .java file.

1. `javadoc App.java`
2. `jar cvfe App.jar App .\`
   [image]
3. Add the jar to Referenced Libraries;
4. Test: when you quote App and hover over it, the description will be displayed. As a result, you put your document after the **Description** so that the java extension catch and show them.
   [image]